# How to implement date logic in a TextFormField in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I need the user to input their birth date in a form. This needs to be validated as a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyyy. How can I guide the user to input this in the correct format and validate it accordingly.

Comment: Why do not you use a date picker and format the date yourself

Comment: You can use TextInputFormatter https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html

Comment: @diegoveloper, I think this link needs updating to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can use [regex ?](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html)

in validating the form

```
validator: (val) => 
          /*Check if regex match*/ ? 'Not a valid date use /*ur formula*/.' : null,
```

or [Text input formatter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html)

or [date picker](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html) ([Example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/date_and_time_picker_demo.dart))